# How do I get a getter property in a class appear when calling Object.keys()?

Tags: javascript, class

```
class cat {
 constructor(first, last) {
   this.firstname = firstname;
   this.lastname = last;
 }
 get fullname() {
   return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname;
 }

}

let homeCat = new Cat("Bella", "Boo");
```

I'm creating a class similar to up above. How do I get `homeCat.fullname` to appear in the property list when calling `Object.keys(homeCat)`?

Comment: You can't, methods of a class are on the prototype, not on the object itself and Object.keys gives you properties on the object, not its prototype. I suggest you create a method that converts your class instance into a POJO with the required keys.

Comment: What is your goal? Why do you need to get `fullname` as a key?

Answer (score 2):

You could define a property for `this` and make it enumerable.

```js
class Cat {
   constructor(first, last) {
       this.firstname = first;
       this.lastname = last;
       Object.defineProperty(this, 'fullname', {
           get () {
               return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname;
           },
           enumerable: true
       });
   }
}


let homeCat = new Cat("Bella", "Boo");

console.log(homeCat.fullname);
console.log(Object.keys(homeCat));
```

Comment: I agree and almost posted a similar answer. However, I thought the OP did not want to change the simple class syntax. One of the drawbacks of this approach is that IDEs won't know that `fullname` is a property and trying to use it from TypeScript would require other hacks. That's why I suggested a method that gives you the current state of the object. Having said that, this may just be what the OP needs

Comment: @JuanMendes TBH, I don't really know what OP *needs*. Depending on what the goal is, there might not actually be a need to do anything like that.

Comment: Thank you @nina-scholz. For me the use case was to make objects "comparable". Especially in jest. Jest's `.isEqual` compares complex object structures based on the keys' values (and loads of other stuff). Therefor my value objects needed to expose the key that they store there value in.